# PHP $_POST arrays with multiple rows

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been reading about arrays created by `$_POST` in PHP. I know that if I submit a form with the follow inputs `ID, Name, Date` I will end up with an array that includes `$_POST = array('IDNo', 'Name', 'Date', 'State')`. 
The point that I'm trying to get to is that I'll have multiple instances of `IDNo, Name, Date, State` submitted at the same time.

I'm fairly sure I can process and sanitize the data once it's been submitted, but I'm not sure how to get it into a multi row array.

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="IDNo" />
    <input type="text" name="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="Date" />
    <input type="radio" name="State1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="IDNo" />
    <input type="text" name="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="Date" />
    <input type="radio" name="State2" />

    <input type="hidden" name="IDNo" />
    <input type="text" name="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="Date" />
    <input type="radio" name="State3" />

    <input type="submit" value="Test Me" />
</form>
```

One thing you'll notice is that the radio input has a unique name for each row. This is related to some jquery implemented on the page. I've seen `IDNo[]` and `Name[]` etc used as this would create the array within the $_POST array, but my unique input name on radio wouldn't work with this, as each radio input would be a different array

Would I be better to append the IDNo or a row number to each input name, or is there another way I can tackle this that I just haven't seen?

Perhaps by changing `State1`, to `state[1]` and changing `IDNo, Name, Date` to `ID[1], Name[1], Date[1]` within the HTML.
What's key for me is that I do it correctly without creating anything that is insecure.

Comment: I would use the array method to be able to loop through the `$_POST`data easily but if a radio input isn't checked, it won't appear in the data and your loop will be wrong.
Using numbers can be better. Then loop through `$_POST` and check existing inputs with `array_keys` and `strpos`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mentioned radio inputs, but there are some inputs which will have no values that I intend to use as part of php arguments.

Comment: an empty input type text will just be empty, but sent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.
One would be:

```
<?php $states = array(1,2,3); ?>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
   <?php foreach ( $states as $state ) : ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'state['.$state.']'; ?>[IDNo]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'state['.$state.']'; ?>[Name]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'state['.$state.']'; ?>[Date]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'state['.$state.']'; ?>" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Test Me" />
</form>
```

You can access these values by using code like `$_POST['state'][1]['Name']`

You can expand the `$states` array to hold more information.

Comment: So essentially `$_POST['State'][1]['Name']` is a numerical array called state, with a sub array which has names.

Comment: I have 2 questions if you don't mind. 1. can i use `<input name="State[1][Name]" />` etc, securely once I sanitise the input correctly? 2. Is there any security concerns around using the actual Unique ID number from MySQL as the `State` number.

Comment: No. Your level of security doesn't depend on record id numbers. What you do with the information before sending it to the database will.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question~

I think it can only use a different name attribute for radio when using form to send http packets~